# Не возвращаются пиксели window.offsetHeight;

Tags: javascript, java

Изучаю *javascript*, не могу понять почему возвращается название переменной `ScrollNum`, вместо количества пикселей от `window.offsetHeight`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        let scrollNum = window.offsetHeight;
        console.log('scrollNum')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в строке console.log('scrollNum') выводите значение в кавычках, чтобы вывести переменную, уберите их. Напишите console.log(scrollNum)